# Overpaid on a low position

Tags: salary

I moved to a lower position within our organization but kept the salary of my previous job due to a legal requirement. I now earn 30% more than my team colleagues doing the same tasks. Do you think I should care about this fact or is it the employer's responsibilty to find an appropiate position for me? In regards to easier/more boring tasks would you accept a lower position with the same money as before at all?

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace! Are you asking if it's common to have this happen? What you should do? I am not sure what you are asking right now.

Comment: I feel bad about it in regards to the team/colleagues. I also do not want to be treated unpleasantly as my employer does not have a suitable position for me. Pls advise what I shall do

Comment: @JamesSmith: What explanation was given for moving you to a "lower" position?

Comment: Thanks Joe, I think you mean by work out a new position or being fired

Comment: Hi Frustrated, I was moved as it appeared I lacked skills for previous position. I was not particular happy neither as the job did not fit my profile

Comment: Make sure you're the first to offer to buy a round of beers if you're out with your teammates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that one of several things will happen. the actual events will depend on your contract, union, and if you work in an at-will location.

- The situation is temporary, they have identified a more appropriate place for you but need an external event to happen. Such events could be win a contract, somebody retire, close an old office, or open a new office.
- The don't have a place for you and have given you a new assignment while they figure out what to do. They feel you have some value.
- This is step one of the process of getting rid of you.

There are risks in all of these. The external event might never happen. They might never find a place for you.

If they are paying you 30% more than other workers, you could be the first to go in a budget crisis. They might be paying your excess pay from overhead or profits or from a contingency fund to carry key employees over coverage gaps.

Unless they have a contractual obligation to keep you or find you a different position, assume that you have entered some sort of danger zone. It would be advisable to freshen the resume, and start looking for positions inside and outside of the company.

Yes boredom can be an issue, but take advantage of the situation to become even more valuable for the company. Take on additional tasks, volunteer for additional duties. Keep your production visible, instead of the fact you are being overpaid.

Yes I would take a position like this if my choice was unemployment.

Comment: Honestly a great advise mhoran, thank you for this. I already take on additional stuff and occasionally solve key problems which other employees can,'t solve. These requests are the reason for the salary difference. I think the main problem is that there is no constant demand for my skill set. I will follow your advise and time will tell what will happen